# What does inch closer mean?

Tags: idioms

I was translating a text and I read:

> It seems you inch closer to my window with each passing day

What does "inch closer" mean? I tried to search on Google but I didn't understood really what does it mean.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: If you google "define inch", the results include "*verb* 1. move slowly and carefully in a specified direction".  Does that help you understand the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means getting closer slowly and gradually, i.e., an inch at a time (1 inch is 2.54cm).